# keydown isn't called when there is no input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

keydown isn't called when there is no input field

I can't catch the escape event in there there is no input field in the dialog.
in the sample bellow it's working only if there is input. when I remove the input, keydown isn't reached.
how can I catch the event of pressing esc or enter in this case?

```js
(function () {
    var dialog = $("#dialog-confirm2")
    .dialog({

        resizable: false,
        height: 150,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: false, //hide x button
    })
    .on('keydown', function (evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE) {
            alert('test');
            <%--more actions to do here--%>
                dialog.dialog('close');
        }
        evt.stopPropagation();
    });
}());
```

```html
<div id="dialog-confirm2">
  Dialog
  <input type="text" /> <%--this is the redundent input i dont need in the dialog--%>
</div>
```

---

new comment 2015-10_27

For Palpatim reuestion i'm adding information.
I tried to adopt the solution you gave me, but the following line isn't called when pressing on escape:
$find("<%=RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequestWithTarget('<%= btnMessageNo.UniqueID %>', '');
See option 1, option 2 and option 3. none of them working.

the full code with your solution:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnMessageNo" runat="server" OnClick="btnMessageNo_Click" Text="Update" CssClass="butttonInProduction" Visible="false" />

<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">

// Store a reference to the key event handler so we can use `off` later
var dialogKeyeventHandler;


// Returns an anonymous event handler, bound to the dialog instance
function makeDialogKeyeventHandler(dialog) {
    return function (evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode === 13) //ENTER
        {
            //$(':button:contains("yes")').click(); //click on yes button
            destroyDialog(dialog);
        }
        else if (evt.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE)
        {
            //alert('inside escape');

            //option 1:
            $(':button:contains("no")').click(); //click on yes button

            //option 2:
            //destroyDialog(dialog);
            //$find("<%=RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequestWithTarget('<%= btnMessageNo.UniqueID %>', '');

            //option 3:
            //$find("<%=RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequestWithTarget('<%= btnMessageNo.UniqueID %>', '');
            //destroyDialog(dialog);
        }
        evt.stopPropagation();
    }
}

function ShowMessage(result) 
{
    if (result == '"confirm"')
    {
        initFocus();

        var message = "Are there any exceptions?";
        document.getElementById('<%=lblConfirmMsg.ClientID %>').innerHTML = message;

        $(function () {
            var dialog = $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 150,
                modal: true,
                closeOnEscape: false, //hide x button
                open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide(); },//hide x button
                buttons:
                {
                    "yes": function ()
                    {
                        //there are exceptions, wait for additional user scan
                        //$(this).dialog("close");
                        destroyDialog(dialog);
                    },
                    "no": function ()
                    {
                        //$(this).dialog("close");
                        destroyDialog(dialog);
                        $find("<%=RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequestWithTarget('<%= btnMessageNo.UniqueID %>', '');
                    },
                    //Cancel: function ()
                    //{
                    //    $(this).dialog("close");
                    //}
                }
            });

            dialogKeyeventHandler = makeDialogKeyeventHandler(dialog);
            $(document).on('keydown', dialogKeyeventHandler);

        });

    }
    else if (result != '')
    {
        alert(result);
        initFocus();
    }
}

// Close the dialog and unbind the key event handler
function destroyDialog(dialog) {
    dialog.dialog('close');
    $(document).off('keydown', dialogKeyeventHandler);
    dialogKeyeventHandler = null;
}

  </script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

Comment: would you be able to clarify what youre trying to do, as i am not understanding what your desired functionality is?

Comment: i'm opening dialog with message to the user (with yes no buttons).
when pressing on enter yes will be pressed and when pressing on esc no will be pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is that key events don't propagate up the container tree the way a normal event does. From the [MDN docs on `keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown):

> target ... Focused element processing the key event, root element if no suitable input element focused.

So, if no input is focused (not just present--your example fails if you deselect the input field or button), then the event target is going to be the root element, or `document` in this case.

However, you don't really want to leave an event handler laying around `document` for those rare cases when you happen to have a dialog up, so what you need to do is add an event handler when you create the dialog, and remove it when you close the dialog.

The example below does that.

```js
// Store a reference to the key event handler so we can use `off` later
var dialogKeyeventHandler;

// Returns an anonymous event handler, bound to the dialog instance
function makeDialogKeyeventHandler(dialog) {
  return function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE) {
      alert('test');
      destroyDialog(dialog);
    }
    evt.stopPropagation();
  }
}

// Creates a dialog and binds a key event handler to `document` to close it if ESC is pressed
function createDialog() {
  var dialog = $("#dialog-confirm2")
  .dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 150,
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false, //hide x button
  });

  dialogKeyeventHandler = makeDialogKeyeventHandler(dialog);
  $(document).on('keydown', dialogKeyeventHandler);
}

// Close the dialog and unbind the key event handler
function destroyDialog(dialog) {
  dialog.dialog('close');
  $(document).off('keydown', dialogKeyeventHandler);
  dialogKeyeventHandler = null;
}

// Open the dialog
createDialog();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="dialog-confirm2">
  Dialog
</div>
```

Comment: the event is called, but this cause problems.

then escape is pressing on no button in this dialog. the no should close the dialog (i'm calling you new destroyDialog) and perform click on another button to call server method. this isn't called:

$find("<%=RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequestWithTarget('<%= btnMessageNo.UniqueID %>', '');

before this new logic, this line was working.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Can you edit your question to **add** additional information? (Don't edit the original question, or future searchers will lose the context of this conversation.)

Comment: how can i add without edit? the comments isn't enough for the code itself.
from code behind i call the java script which open jquery ui dialog message with yes no button. if you press on yes, the dialog is closed. if he press on no, the dialog is closed and a method is called on the server using the following line:
$find("<%=RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequestWithTarget('<%= btnMessageNo.UniqueID %>', '');
but this line isn't called when i insert your logic.
enter should be equal to pressing on no and esc should be equal to pressing on yes.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean to say is, "Don't change the original question, instead, edit to add new information." Regarding pressing "Yes" and "no": Your dialog doesn't have a "yes" or "no" button, so I can't directly know what you're talking about. However, you can adapt the code above in any number of ways. For example, you might include a "state" parameter when you invoke the `destroyDialog` method, and take appropriate action based on that state.

Comment: i added comments inside the original question body. Please have a look.

Comment: Based on what I'm seeing of your code, you aren't properly addressing the jQuery elements. Your new update includes in the event handler: `$(':button:contains("no")')`, but the only button I see referenced has the text "Update". (Also, I don't know what HTML the `asp:Button` directive renders; if it's an `input` rather than a `button` element, jQuery's `:contains` selector won't work as expected. Put an alert in the event handler. If it fires, your problem is not in the firing of the event handler, but somewhere else in your logic and you should ask another question to address that problem.

Comment: the dialog code contain buttons yes and no, see the updated full example. the no is pressed, if i placed alert inside the code of button no, it's reached when pressing on escape and calling 
$(':button:contains("no")').click();
The ajax call is done if we reach this code when pressing on no and not via escape.

Comment: I don't recommend simulating clicks as a reliable way of invoking things. I'd suggest that you refactor the code that you want to execute on each of the button press and ESC key press into a standalone function, then invoke that function instead.

Comment: moving the code to a function didn't solve the issue, however calling the ajax in function using setTimeout solve it:
setTimeout(function () { performNoInServer(); }, 0);
the combination with you sulution solved the issue. thanks a lot.
why can't i give you more points?